# AWS Disk Image Challenge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have some files and data on One of my AWS ec2 instances. **There is a Base state of that data.**

Every day, a Bot updates, Edits, modify that data. (Basically to test the bot's performance).

I want that bot to start working on the same data every day, (Which is the **base state**).

At the moment, I am creating that data every day manually, so that I can ensure it's the same data every day. (This is a very tedious and time taking process and I want to solve this problem in this question.)

Can Anyone Please suggest some approach Here, I am having in mind to have something like creating an image of that directory and every morning just loading that image itself into my instance, But not sure what to do there.

Thanks,

Comment: Simple solution would be to just have the bot copy the data before modifying, leaving the originals untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Agree with the above comment. You can simply create a base image and lunch ec2 instance every day whenever you want to test with a base setup.
I would say in case you can make it automate as well.